# PrimeFaces and Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, netbeans, primefaces

This is my first experince using Spring on a project, I'm using PrimeFaces and Hibernate, and I need to integrate Spring security as well, the thing is that after doing the pom.xml configuration the project runs but the PrimeFaces "look and feel" disappeared, and I don't know why is happening.

here's my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sebana</groupId>
    <artifactId>sisafsebana</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>sisafsebana</name>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
<dependency>
<groupId>mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
<version>5.1.23</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate core -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate core library dependecy start -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
 <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
 <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
 <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
 <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>cglib</groupId>
 <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
 <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Hibernate core library dependecy end -->

        <!-- Hibernate query library dependecy start -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>antlr</groupId>
 <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
 <version>2.7.7</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Hibernate query library dependecy end -->


<!-- Hibernate query library dependecy end -->


  <!-- For Java EE Application Server, uncomment this library 
  and comment the rest of the libraries
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  -->

  <!-- For Servlet Container like Tomcat -->
  <!-- http://download.java.net/maven/2 -->
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
 <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
 <version>2.1.0-b03</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
 <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
 <version>2.1.0-b03</version>
</dependency>
<!-- EL 2.2 to support method parameter in EL -->
    <dependency>
 <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
 <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
 <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ -->
    <dependency>
 <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
 <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
 <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
 <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
 <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
 <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
 <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
 <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org/</url>
            <id>PrimeFaces-maven-lib</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library PrimeFaces-maven-lib</name>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

I'm using PrimeFaces 5.0

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently developing a similar project with a Tomcat server. And my pom (the relevant parts) look like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.18</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-el-api</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.18</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-jasper-el</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.javaee.web-api.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.webmvc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.faces.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.webflow.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${com.sun.faces.jsf.api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${com.sun.faces.jsf.implementation.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>se.jiderhamn</groupId>
        <artifactId>classloader-leak-prevention</artifactId>
        <version>${se.jiderhamn.classloader.leak.prevention.version}             </version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>${org.primefaces.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>${org.primefaces.extensions.version}</version>
    </dependency>`
```

And my web.xml looks like this:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1">

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>5</session-timeout>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>

<listener>
    <description>Classloader leak check</description>
    <listener-class>se.jiderhamn.classloader.leak.prevention.ClassLoaderLeakPreventor</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <description>Spring Framework configuration location</description>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:configuration/spring/*-config.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.apache.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>server</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession</param-name>
    <param-value>3</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews</param-name>
    <param-value>1</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.allowTextChildren</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter>
    <description>Spring character encoding filter</description>
    <display-name>Spring character encoding filter</display-name>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <description>UTF-8 encoding</description>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <description>Force UTF-8</description>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/flow/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And my faces-config.xml looks like this:

```
<faces-config xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
          version="2.2">
</faces-config>
```

And the last two files you need to make something work is something of a base template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

</html>
```

And a view page in which to include your template. Again, this version is stripped, but if you have any questions, feel free to ask:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition template="_basetemplate.xhtml"                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
</ui:composition>
```

As you see in my view, I include my base template in which I define some regions, though I think this is all you need to make things work. Also, I think you can exclude this dependency from your pom.xml since primefaces is in xhtml and you don't really need jsps for that.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
<artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
<version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm using Spring Webflow and i did not include that config here but that is pretty straight forward too, and again, if I missed something or your wonder anything, don't hesitate to ask.