# Create JSF 2.0 with Richfaces 4.0 / Primefaces project using Maven

Tags: hibernate, jsf-2, primefaces, maven-2, richfaces

I am new to JSF and Richfaces. I am in need to create a project with 
JSF 2.0 , Richfaces 4.0 , Hibernate using Maven.

I have go through many tutorials and I am so confused about installing maven archtypes, plugins , adding repositories etc.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and eclipse (kepler) and MySQL .

I have installed maven using `Sudo apt-get install Maven2`

Help me to get clear knowledge and to create a new project (for beginner) using

- JSF 2.0
- Richfaces 4 / Primefaces  (Able to remove Richfaces & add Primefaces and vice versa)
- Maven
- Hibernate
- Spring (If needed how to use)

Comment: check this liknk it may be helpful: http://www.onlinetechvision.com/jsf2-primefaces3-spring3-hibernate4-integration-project/

Comment: Do you have any experience with Maven, or Hibernate, or JSF or Spring? Do you have to create your ORM from scratch, or will you import the hibernate ORM as a client? And why are you using older maven version (2 instead of 3) and an old Eclipse? Your question seem too broad I'm afraid..

Comment: @yannicuLar - I had worked on JSF 1.2 Richfaces 3.3.0 and Hibernate with Maven2 (Not used Spring). Till now, I am just updating the extra modules in pre-created project. I stuck to create a new one. I have used mvn archetype:generate but it is not fulfilled. Now I will replace Maven 3 instead of Maven 2. Say me the basics( How to step in to add jars, repositories, etc) to create a project above mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be like:

1. Install a new Eclipse. There are so many elipse-maven plugin issues that have been resolved since Kepler.
2. Start a new maven 3 project, with a webapp archetype like `maven-archetype-webapp`, just to create a proper folder structure
3. Add the dependencies you need to integrate with Spring, JSF-2, Hibernate etc. Pick them one by one, and make sure you are using the right versions, usually the latest release.stable version.

For example, [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces) you can see all the versions for primefaces

I think that [this](http://coderspirit.blogspot.gr/2014/12/spring4-hibernae4-jsf2-primefaces5-jee.html) would be a good tutorial for a starter.
You can also check pom files from [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29438419/879368) projects, and handpick some dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can just install maven first as a external plugin for your Ide(eclipse) you can read this tuto:http://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/installing-maven-plugin-for-existing-eclipse-ide
therefore you can just create a maven project with file->new->maven project
and for the primefaces /jsf/hibernate maven will take care of all of them you need just to add the right dependencies in the file pom.xml for ex: for Hibernate you need to add :

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
<version>3.4.0.GA</version>
```